# Dagger2 issue with "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method."

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to setup a new project with Dagger2, I've used Dagger2 before, but now I'm trying to set it up from scratch by myself. I'm getting the example from a Kotlin project that I'm part of, but can't set it up for Java the same way as it works in Kotlin right now (or maybe I'm missing something).

It's just a single Component, single Module and Application.

***Component***

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MainAppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {
@Component.Builder
abstract class Builder implements AndroidInjector.Factory<App> {

    public AppComponent create(App application) {
        seedApplication(application);
        return build();
    }

    @BindsInstance
    abstract void seedApplication(App application);

    abstract AppComponent build();
}
}
```

***Module***

```
@Module
abstract class MainAppModule {

@Binds
abstract public Application bindApplication(App application);

@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract public MainActivity contributeActivityInjector();
}
```

***Application ***

```
public class App extends DaggerApplication {

@Override
public AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this);
}
}
```

At this point I don't have any classes that I call with `@Inject` 
I'm just getting error at build time:

```
 error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {
        ^
```

Of course `cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.` seems to be the problem, but I just don't know how to solve it. It works fine on my kotlin project, that somebody else set up.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, can you please show us your dagger-related lines in your gradle file (or other build file)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like you are missing [AndroidInjectionModule](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/android/AndroidInjectionModule.html) (or [AndroidSupportInjectionModule](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.11/dagger/android/support/AndroidSupportInjectionModule.html) if you use support fragments) installed on you `AppComponent`.

It should be like:

```
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, MainAppModule.class})
```

Comment: Hi @KursoR, Unfortunately this gives the same error.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` ;/

Comment: Maybe now this is another error?
`Map<Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends BroadcastReceiver>>` is provided by AndroidInjectionModule ([source](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjectionModule.java)), so it should be resolved

Comment: You are so right, thank you so much. I would very much appreciate some explanation of these additional modules and why do I have to add them (I don't have them in Kotlin project). Weird stuff. Anyway. Thanks so much.